# How to use a variable inside .expression() as conditional statements criteria in google earth engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, image-segmentation

I am trying to automate a segmentation process in google earth engine.

I have some parameters calculated outside of the .expression() function and needed to be used in defining different criteria inside the .expression() to segment images. An example of my code is as follow:

```js
var meanV = normalizedTh.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: boundry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var stdV = normalizedTh.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  geometry: boundry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var mean =ee.Number(meanV.get('b7'));

var std = ee.Number(stdV.get('b7'));

var hT = mean.add(std);

var lT = mean.subtract(std);

print(mean,std,hT,lT)


//----Segmenting the image-----

var segmentedTh = normalizedTh.expression(
      "(b('b7') > hT ) ? 3" +
      ": (b('b7')  > mean ) ? 2" +
      ": (b('b7') < lT ) ? 1" +
      ":  0 "
          );

//----Visualizing the results----

var thpalette = ['FFA500','red', '1E90FF    ','blue'];
Map.addLayer(segmentedTh.clip(boundry), {min: 0, max: 3, palette: thpalette}, 'Segmented th');
```

I am getting this error:
`segmented th: Layer error: Image.parseExpression: Expression contains undeclared variables: [hT, lT, mean].`

Apparently, I need to convert the calculated parameter outside the expression() to some format which could be used in conditional statements inside it.
Would you please help me to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :),

It needs to define the parameters inside the .expression():

```js
var segmentedTh = normalizedTh.expression(
      "(b('b7') > hT) ? 3" +
      ": (b('b7')  > mean) ? 2" +
      ": (b('b7') < lT) ? 1" +
      ": 0 ",
      {
      'hT': hT ,
      'mean': ee.Number(meanV.get('b7')),
      'lT': lT
});
```